# Why this regex pattern matching does not work

Tags: java, regex

I am implementing RESTful query with JPA specification. Would like to handle url with multiple criteria that looks like this:

`http://localhost:8080/samples?search=lastName:doe,age>25`

The search string would match pattern `(\\w+?)(:|<|>)(\\w+?)` separated by ",".

Therefore, I wrote the following code to obtain Matcher from a string:

```
static Matcher getMatcherFromString(String str) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+?)(:|<|>)(\\w+?),");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str + ",");
    return matcher;
}
```

This method is then called in controller to parse the url.

However, when I tested the method with string `analysisId:fdebfd6e-d046-4192-8b97-ac9f65dc2009`, it returns null. Why did I do wrong for the pattern matching?

Comment: I'd say because `\w` does not match `-`

Comment: @Fallenhero `\w` is for words. What should I use instead?

Comment: I don't know what you like to match, but maybe `[0-9a-zA-Z_-]`?

Comment: or easier (if supported) `[\w-]`

Comment: @Fallenhero tried both `([a-zA-Z_-])(:|<|>)([0-9a-zA-Z_-])` and `([\w-])(:|<|>)([\w-])` and still does not work. I think the individual pattern is fine. It is the matcher groups that is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this to work: (\w+?)(:|<|>)[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*,

I used this to figure it out: https://regex101.com/r/fOEzd9/1

I think the main problem was the numbers makes \w not match as a word. You also need to account for the dashes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved using this string:

```
"(\\w+?)(:|<|>)(\\w+?),"
```